# Why wouldn't I be able to delete this row? SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server

I just have a table that has two rows of data and want to delete the rows and SQL Server Management Studio is choking on my delete big time. Here is the error pop up.

[image]

All I'm doing is highlighting the row and clicking the delete key. This error doesn't make any sense to me at all!  The only way I've been able to get rid of the rows is to drop and recreate the tables but that isn't acceptable down the road when I only want to remove one or two rows.

Comment: It means the table does not have a primary key, so SSMS cannot guarantee that only those two rows will be deleted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql delete row error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344313/sql-delete-row-error)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Primary Key to your table. Run this two queries
First add a candidate column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_admin ADD TempID int IDENTITY(1, 1);
```

Then make this column the table primary key

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_admin
    ADD CONSTRAINT pk_tbl_admin 
        PRIMARY KEY (TempId);
```